# Online Pop-up website message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I don't know that much of PHP and javascript but I know HTML and a bit of CSS.

I'd like to make a website that receives the messages in pop-ups. So the receiver will get the message and will direct him to that tab if he's on a different tab.
Basically this is for a game on facebook and we have a clan. We need to make the clan members be aware which clan to attack so I came up with this idea.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUCkD.png

! (I already have a website to put the page up.)

I'd like a blank webpage with the script of the pop-up.
and another webpage that has the text box to put in the message and sent it to that website.

I don't know if you understand my explanation but I think that's the closest I can explain to you. Please help guys, Thank you

Comment: And no, I can't use facebook chat or something else. Because they can minimize it or even if you can't minimize it they'll still ignore it and do something else. With the pop-up idea, it will go directly to that TAB and has to click Ok. then he/she will do his/her job.

Comment: to accept an answer, hover beside it and click the tick

Comment: `Because they can minimize it or even if you can't minimize it they'll still ignore it and do something else` - they can also not open your page, so, you can't control what other people do on their browsers, nor can you hijack a browser in such a way as to demand a user does what you want them to do before being able to do what they want

Comment: Okay, I just want it as I want it to be :/ I know the popup is sorted but still haven't sorted the sending box part.

I need another webpage which has a box which I can put my message then it'll appear in the pop-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put javascript in html, it's like this:

```
<script>
JAVASCRIPT GOES HERE
</script>
```